# How do I make a custom path identifier?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

To define what I mean by "custom path identifier", I mean a short set of character(s) that represent a whole path, and example of this would be the `~`, if you type `cd ~` in your Terminal Emulator it will go to your home folder.  But I'd like to make a custom one for a different path.  I looked in the `.bashrc` folder for hints on how to do this, but I could find anything unfortunately.

---

The "custom path identifier" I'm trying to make is `~~` to `/home/myuser/Applications/Custom/Java/`.  Since I'm going to be using that path a lot ( and daily) I don't want to keep retyping the whole path, and just typing `~~` would be nice.  I tried using the `alias` command:

```
alias ~~="/home/myuser/Applications/Custom/Java/"
```

But, unfortunately this did not work.

---

On the side note, I apologize if I used the wrong terminology for anything, I'm fairly new to all this Linux stuff and I know very little.  So thanks for any extra information I get.

Comment: You can use alias ~~="cd /home/myuser/Applications/Custom/Java/" and you can execute ~~ to cd to /home/myuser/Applications/Custom/Java/

Comment: @Nischay, That is a very good solution.  But it doesn't answer the question "How do I make a custom path identifier?".  Thanks though!

Comment: In zsh, you get just the syntax you proposed - named dirs are handeled like user directories, especially in the shell prompt. (See my answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tilde (`~`) has a special meaning in bash, is an expansion of bash and takes the value of `$HOME` environment variable. Read [Tilde Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) section from GNU Bash Reference Manual to understant how it wors. So, I think that what you want to accomplish is something similar to:

```
myuser@ubuntu:~$ pushd -n "/home/myuser/Applications/Custom/Java"
~ ~/Applications/Custom/Java
myuser@ubuntu:~$ cd ~1
myuser@ubuntu:~/Applications/Custom/Java$
```

Read `man pushd` for more info.

Next, to go directly inside of `/home/myuser/Applications/Custom/Java` everytime when you will run `cd ~1` command in your terminal just add the following line to the  end of your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
pushd -n "/home/myuser/Applications/Custom/Java" >/dev/null
```

Reload your `~/.bashrc` file with `source ~/.bashrc` and then use `cd ~1` everytime when you want to change the current working directory to `/home/myuser/Applications/Custom/Java`.

Comment: Brilliant solution, but it works only if you do not perform  `popd` up to empty the directory stack. At that point needs to be recharged file `.bashrc` or rerun the `pushd` command.

Comment: @girardengo This can be solved also by adding the following alias in `~/.bash_aliases` file: `alias popd='popd && pushd -n "/home/myuser/Applications/Custom/Java" >/dev/null'`

Answer (score 0):

In **zsh** this is dead easy, because you don't need to write `cd` explicitly, you can simply create an alias like this:

```
alias x=/some/path
```

Add this to your `.zshrc` (or whatever file you will source on the zsh startup) and you're ready to go. Now you can jump to this directory by calling the alias, namely `x` in this example.

Comment: Use **`cdable_vars`** (see my answer), and you can just set a variable, not an alias (which is a command, it not a `zsh` global alias): `x=/some/path`. **Works with bash too!**

Answer (score 0):

You could use the shell option `"cdable_vars"`

```
shopt -s cdable_vars
```

Also, take a look at `CDPATH`,
and the shell option `"autocd"`

For the description of how `CDPATH` works, see the `cd` section in the man page of bash

`man bash | less -p 'cd \['`

The solutions work for both `bash` and `zsh`.

If you use `zsh`, you can use **global aliases** to replace an identifier everywhere in the command line, not just as command.

Answer (score 0):

You can also customize your alias just like I do

```
alias work = "cd ~ && cd /home/anish/workspace"
```

It's also the better approch suppose you are in some directory and you have to navigate to different this might be easy

Comment: That’s not quite right - you need to put in the name of the alias before the =